# How do I create a sash in Perl Tkx?

Tags: perl, tkx

Does anyone know how to create a sash object in Perl Tkx? I am using ActivePerl and Perl 5.10.

Answer (score 4):

Sashes are created for you automatically when you create widgets that need them.  For example, Paned Windows, created via `new_ttk__panedwindow()` as in [this tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/onepage.html).